# Convergence of powers when we have convergence in $L^\infty$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p,q\in L^\infty$. Further, let $\Vert p-q\Vert_\infty<\epsilon$. Can we bound the following? Particularly showing that as $\Vert p-g\Vert_\infty\rightarrow 0$ then it also goes to $0$.
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert p(t)^\alpha-g(t)^\alpha\vert dt
\end{align}
here we assume $0<\alpha\leq 2$ and $\alpha$ may not be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, consider the constant functions $p = 0$ and $q = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then $\|p-q\|_{\infty} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, but
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |p(t)^{\alpha}-q(t)^{\alpha}| \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)^{\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}t = \infty$$
for all $\alpha > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion above isn't true. Take
\begin{align*}
p(x) = \min\left(1, \frac{1}{|x|}\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad p_n(x) = \min\left(1, \frac{1}{|x|^{1 - 1/n}}\right)
\end{align*}
for $n \ge 2$. We clearly see that $p, p_n \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $|p - p_n|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R})} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But, for example, taking $\alpha = 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R}|p(x) - p_n(x)| dx = \int_{1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x^{1-1/n}}-\frac{1}{x}\right) dx \ge \int_{2}^\infty \frac{x^{1/n} - 1}{x} dx \ge \int_{2}^\infty \frac{2^{1/n} - 1}{x} dx
\end{align*}
which diverges for any finite $n \ge 2$.